# How can I retrive the AWS Cognito user from from a valid access token using aws-amplify library?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I just want to retrieve the Cognito user attributes and other details by using a valid jwt access token produced when the user signed in earlier.

I use Nodejs and want to know whether there is a way to do this with the aws-amplify library.

Answer (score 0):

We can decode the JWT using a third-party library like [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode). The payload contains the details themselves.

Answer (score -1):

There is a method in aws-amplify library that you can use for this purpose.

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
    bypassCache: false  // Optional, By default is false. If set to true, this call will send a request to Cognito to get the latest user data
}).then(user => console.log(user))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

You will see `attributes` field in the response's payload.

If you face any problems, please check the official [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js#retrieve-current-authenticated-user)

> This method can be used to check if a user is logged in when the page is loaded. It will throw an error if there is no user logged in. This method should be called after the Auth module is configured or the user is logged in.

Comment: I want to retrieve the user from a JWT token. Not from currentAuthenticatedUser.

Comment: If you are using aws-amplify package, there is no need for you to store JWT token and deal with refresh token logic etc. aws-amplify does that for you, if you use currentAuthenticatedUser method. Moreover, you asked for a way to get user attributes with aws-amplify package.